# send-mailmessage replaces html style tags with System.String[]

Tags: html, email, powershell-2.0

I am trying to use `send-mailmessage` to send an email in powershell (v2).

I run a MySQL Query, and convert it to html as follows:

```
$htmlbody = $mysqlresult | `
ConvertTo-Html -property field1, `
field2, `
field3 `
-pre "<style>table{border: 3px solid #000000;}</style>"
```

I then send an email as:

```
Send-MailMessage -to "$ToAddress" `
    -From "$FromAddress" `
    -Subject "Subject Line" `
    -BodyasHtml "$htmlbody" `
    -SmtpServer "$SMTP"
```

The email sends, and I get my email with the data in a table. 
But the ... section gets replaced with `System.String[]`

As far as I can tell, there's no 'funny' characters in there. Can anyone explain why this is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select your properties before piping the objects into `ConvertTo-Html`:

```
$htmlbody = $mysqlresult |
            select field1, field2, field3 |
            ConvertTo-Html -Pre '<style>...</style>'
```

Depending on what datatype of the fields actually have you may need to mangle string arrays into strings first, for instance via [calculated properties](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx). Example:

```
$htmlbody = $mysqlresult |
            select field1, field2, @{n='field3';e={$_.field3 -join ' '}} |
            ConvertTo-Html -Pre '<style>...</style>'
```

Comment: cheers, I thought it might be something simple (apparently not). In the end I ended up constructing the html manually using the `-fragment` option of `ConvertTo-html`, which seems to work.